# How to keep list on page on browser refresh?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Currently, as it stands I was able to get the array to store in local storage. The `creatTask` function displays the task on the page.

What I am trying to achieve now is that the list stays on the page when the browser is refreshed. That is the outcome I am looking for.

```
const el = {
  form: document.querySelector(".form"),
  input: document.querySelector(".user-input"),
  list: document.querySelector(".list"),
  date: document.querySelector(".date"),
  time: document.querySelector(".time"),
};
//local storage key

const storage_key = "tasks-storage-key";

//Create ID

const createId = () =>
  `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}${new Date().getTime()}`;

//variable of empty array that gets new task
let taskList = [];


//function that creates new tasks with date and time
const creatTask = (task) => {
  
  const data = {
   id: createId(),
  taskNew: el.input.value,
  taskDate:el.date.value,
   taskTime: el.time.value,
}

  if (!data.taskNew) {
    alert("Please add a new Task");
  }
  if (!data.taskDate) {
    alert("Please add a new Task with a due date");
  }
  if (!data.taskTime) {
    alert("Please add a new Task with a due time");
  }

  const tasks = document.createElement("div");

  tasks.innerHTML = `
       <div class="task-content">
        <div class="task" data-id="${data.id}">
        <div class="new-task-created">${data.taskNew}</div>
        <label class="due-date">${data.taskDate}</label>
        <label class="due-time">${data.taskTime}</label>
    </div>

    <div class="atcion-buttons">
        <button onclick="editItem()" class="edit" data-id="${data.id}">Edit</button>
        <button onclick="deleteItem()" class="delete" data-id="${data.id}">Delete</button>
        <button onclick="completeItem()" class="complete" data-id="${data.id}">Complete</button>
    </div>
</div>`;

  taskList.push(data);
  el.list.appendChild(tasks);
  storeList();
};

function displayTasks(taskList){
  let tasksHtml = []
  for(task of tasks){
    tasksHtml.push(` 
    <div class="task-content">
        <div class="task" data-id="${data.id}">
        <div class="new-task-created">${data.taskNew}</div>
        <label class="due-date">${data.taskDate}</label>
        <label class="due-time">${data.taskTime}</label>
    </div>`);
  }
  return tasksHtml;
}

//event listner that listens for add button.
function addTask() {
  creatTask();
}

//function that stores task list.
function storeList() {

  let arraytask = JSON.stringify(taskList);
  localStorage.setItem(storage_key, arraytask);

  let storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storage_key)) || [];
}
```

Comment: and what is not working about the current implementation?

Comment: I updated the code. What I want the local storage to do is keep the list that ahs been created on the page to stay there, on page refresh.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle link, or a reproducable example?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/blaze92/L8zm1e3r/

So when you create a task, the task is meant to remain on the page when the page reloads/refreshed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This successfully gets the list of stored tasks from local storage.

```
let taskList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storage_key)) || [];
```

So you will have access to that data when the page reloads. What you need to do then is probably update your code that sets the innerHtml because it just adds 1 task to HTML which means you can't display more and also it runs in createTask.

You should create a separate function that sets the innerHTML with given list of tasks, call it when the page loads. you can add the line under the taskList definition, such as:

```
displayTasks(taskList) -> returns the html of tasks
```

To implement that function you will need to do something like this:

```
let tasksHtml = []
for (task of tasks) {
tasksHtml.push(
    <div class="task-content">
        <div class="task" data-id="${task.id}">
        <div class="new-task-created">${task.taskNew}</div>
        <label class="due-date">${task.taskDate}</label>
        <label class="due-time">${task.taskTime}</label>
    </div>)
}

return tasksHtml;
```

Comment: I tried that, Does not seem to work. I updated my js code so you can see the whole code.

Comment: why did you accept the answer?